# DB2 insert performance - How to measure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning, db2

*[From stackoverflow]*
Im trying to find a way to speedup my inserts to a DB2 9.7.1 (ubuntu linux)

Im watching vmstat and trying to gather some statistics via the db2 get snapshot commands but im not able to figure out which numbers im looking for to be able to see where the trouble is.

I've read lits of stuff like http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35692526/question-multiple-row-in.aspx, and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0403wilkins/ and tricks like

```
ALTER TABLE lalala APPEND ON
```

works somewhat (the difference between a dd if=/dev/zero and insert is still a factor 10) but I would like to be able to find the counters or other performance indicators that actually show **why** it makes sense to use those tricks.

For example:

- What is the metric called that shows me that it is buffer pages allocation (FSCR stuff) that is the problem
- Where do I see that the insert time is hampered by clustered indexes?

I find `db2top` very useful but im still searching for more direct view of "this is your bottleneck" methods

Answer (score 1):

I find measuring io performances of database useful.

Try iostat , htop.

I presume you have indexed the database correctly. Optimal database design cannot be beaten.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this (?):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0403wilkins/index.html

This can also be an interesting lecture:

www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0403wilkins/index.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the link. I've seen and used it. The link provided for the lecture seems to be the same as the insert tips?

Comment: It is indeed, sorry .. my bad